# scrapy + splash : not rendering full page javascript data

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am just exploring scrapy with splash and I am trying to scrape all the product (pants) data with productid,name and price   from one of the e-commerce site
[gap](http://www.gap.com/browse/category.do?cid=80799&sop=true&departmentRedirect=true#pageId=0&department=75) but I didn't see all the dynamic product data loaded when I see from splash web UI [splash web UI](http://192.168.0.15:8050) (only 16 items are loading though for every request - no clue why)
I tried with the following options but no luck

- Increasing wait time upto 20 sec
- By starting the docker with "**--disable-private-mode**"
- By using lua_script for page scrolling
- With view report full option **splash:set_viewport_full()**

```js
lua_script2 = """ function main(splash)
    local num_scrolls = 10
    local scroll_delay = 2.0

    local scroll_to = splash:jsfunc("window.scrollTo")
    local get_body_height = splash:jsfunc(
        "function() {return document.body.scrollHeight;}"
    )
    assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
    splash:wait(splash.args.wait)

    for _ = 1, num_scrolls do
        scroll_to(0, get_body_height())
        splash:wait(scroll_delay)
    end        
    return splash:html()
end"""                 
                              
            yield SplashRequest(
                url,
                self.parse_product_contents,
                endpoint='execute', 
                args={
                        'lua_source': lua_script2,
                        'wait': 5,
                    }
                )
```

Can anyone please shed some light on this behavior? 
p.s : I am using scrapy framework and I am able to parse the product information (itemid,name and price) from the render.html (but render.html has only 16 items information)

Comment: How about using the api to get the data directly instead of so much effort ? "http://www.gap.com/resources/productSearch/v1/search?cid=80799"

Comment: Hi Tarun, Thanks for the reply. But my goal is to crawl into each product listed on the site (for example here each pant) and get all the skus available  (for example this pant has nearly 23 size (skus) that I can see from view-source [link](http://www.gap.com/browse/product.do?cid=80868&pcid=80799&vid=1&pid=844309052)  which i didn't find through api. I am new this api approach . can you please give some information

Comment: I have tried to use **splash:set_viewport_full()** but no luck and tried with scrpay also like 
**yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_product_contents, args={'wait': 10, 'viewport':'full' , 'render_all': 1},endpoint='render.html' )**

Still no luck

But when I set the view report size a large dimensions
`splash:set_viewport_size(1980, 8020)` 
I saw the content got loaded but still it has limitation. got this error when I try to increase dimension of the png 
`Viewport is out of range (20000x20000, area=16000000)`

Comment: @TarunLalwani do you have any thoughts, please share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated the script to below

```
function main(splash)
    local num_scrolls = 10
    local scroll_delay = 2.0
    splash:set_viewport_size(1980, 8020)
    local scroll_to = splash:jsfunc("window.scrollTo")
    local get_body_height = splash:jsfunc(
        "function() {return document.body.scrollHeight;}"
    )
    assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
--    splash:set_viewport_full()
    splash:wait(10)
    splash:runjs("jQuery('span.icon-x').click();")
    splash:wait(1)
    for _ = 1, num_scrolls do
        scroll_to(0, get_body_height())
        splash:wait(scroll_delay)
    end      

      splash:wait(30)

    return { 
        png = splash:png(),
        html = splash:html(),
        har = splash:har()
       }
end
```

And ran it in my local splash, the png doesn't work fine but the HTML has the last product

[image: Last Image on page]

[image: Splash Rendered HTML]

The only issue was when the email subscribe popup is there it won't scroll, so I added code to close it

Comment: thats great ! but when I tried to run the same script in my local splash I got bad request error. Is there anything I need to get it work? please tell me


`
{
    "type": "ScriptError",
    "error": 400,
    "description": "Error happened while executing Lua script",
    "info": {
        "line_number": 9,
        "type": "LUA_ERROR",
        "source": "[string \"function main(splash)\r...\"]",
        "message": "Lua error: [string \"function main(splash)\r...\"]:9: network3",
        "error": "network3"
    }
}`

Comment: I pulled the latest docker image of splash, may be you are using something old? also try changing `function main(splash)` to `function main(splash, args)`

Comment: I have pulled the docker image 3days ago (**docker pull scrapinghub/splash**) I believe it is latest one. I have tried with **function main(splash, args)** same network issue I faced. Let me check the docker once again. did you by any chance pull by **pull scrapinghub/splash:master** ?

Comment: No, just  `pull scrapinghub/splash` and i ran in the browser renderer

Comment: I think the splash is giving response after I made multiple requests. and intermittently giving the bad request error. wired !

Comment: Increase the timeouts

Comment: Thanks Tarun for your help ! one more thing at this point is how to find the no.of scrolls here (like on which parameter we can decide the dynamic rendering is completed ?) rather than giving much wait time via Lua

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153854/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-tez).